# Powering a 9V LED setup, with 3x3V CR3032's

Tags: led

I have a model kit I built a few years back with a custom LED lighting kit. It is powered by a 9V battery. Since then, I have built another model, and this one, because it wasn't a custom lighting kit and I did it myself, was just 3 LED lights powered by a single 3V CR2032 button battery. My question is this: I love so much the smaller space taken up by the button batteries.. and was wondering if it was possible to cut the 9V battery out from the older model and simply reconnect and replace the single 9V with THREE 3V 2032's? Mathematically that would seem to add up.. but I'm sure that's probably not how electricity works.. ;-)
I also recognize that the longevity of the 2032's would be far less than the single 9V, but that's ok as I only power these things up to show them off and it's infrequent.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice!
Steven

Comment: Your logic seems reasonable. Just be sure you wire 3 of them in series with correct polarity: -ve of one to +ve of the next.

Comment: dims quickly because coincells have highESR soit works for a dayand very dim for a couplemore

Comment: Thanks guys! Appreciate all the thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it depends on how the LEDs are wired. If there in series you will not have enough voltage to light them. If they are in parallel which I doubt you could light them. You could rewire the three Leds to a parallel configuration, and that should work. Also it will draw 3X the current cutting battery life if that is of concern. If this does not cover it please post a schematic as you plan on wiring it.

Comment: Considering it worked with the 9V PP3, I see no reason why it wouldn't work from any 9V source with sufficiently low internal resistance, with no other changes necessary. The real concern is internal resistance of the cells. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Three in series yes they will work.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!